# Comment in multiline string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, comments, multiline

Is there a possibility to add comment inside a javascript multiline string?

Something like this:

```
var string = 'START - \
This is part of my string\
\\ This should be escaped!\
-END ';

// string = 'START - This is part of my string - END';
```

Thanks

Comment: to add comment on long strings

Comment: I don't think there are any other options apart from your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible this way. You can do:

```
var s = "multi line" +
        //" line" +
        " string";
```

Answer (score 4):

I found one possibility:

```
var string ='START - \
This is my string'+
// This should be escaped!
' - END';

// string = 'START - This is my string - END'
```

But it's not so nice...

Comment: Better than nothing. Sometimes I really want to comment something in a multiline string for experimenting with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this?

```
var string = 'This is part of your string';
string += 'This is second part of your string'; //Comment yout want to add
string += 'This is thirdpart of your string';
```